# I dont want quicktime player to launch in my ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, quicktime

So I'm making a  ios app in xcode and its a radio app. Whenever i press the play button the quicktime player launches and plays through the quicktime player. I want to make it so it doesn't and still display the amount of time its been playing(MM:SS). (M= Minutes S= Seconds)

My Code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIWebView *hotjamz;
}
-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender {
NSString *stream = @"http://www.hot108.com/hot108.pls";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];

NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[hotjamz loadRequest:urlrequest];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using a `UIWebView` to play back your media content. You won't have any control over the media player being used there. You have several options to get the control you want:

1. Use one of the built-in media playing classes, such as MPMoviePlayerController, to play back your media and customize the UI yourself (AVFoundation also provides playback capabilities, if you need to go lower level)
2. Build a player in HTML, and load that into the `UIWebView` you're currently using.

Comment: Its a Radio Station. Its there a way i could use like AVFoundation? I Heard things about it but i dont know how to Use it with the code.